# Error mandando datos por AJAX a Metodo en ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hola amigos estoy trabajando con **ASP.NET** / **C#** y pues estoy tratando de pasar una parametro a través de un **AJAX** ... pero obtengo esté error, hace poco publiqué una pregunta muy similar, donde hacía lo mismo pero desde un **ActionLink** pero como ahora estoy pasando el parametro por **js** me imagino que he de estar errando en otra parte. Gracias a toda la gente hermosa y brillante de Stack ... los amo :D

este es mi error :

[image: Aquí podemos ver que el error al hacer el http request]

esto es lo que estoy tratando de hacer ...

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    //getting id parameter value
    var selects = document.getElementById("id_req").value;
    var id_x = parseInt(selects);
    alert(id_x);

    //ajax man u.u_-
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '@Url.Action("UniqueRequest", "Request")',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        //al parecer mi error está porque asp.net no reconoce mi id
        // la solución en asp.net era algo así:
        //  (new { id = 123 },null) ... ya lo probé aquí en js y nada u.u
        'id': id_x
      },
      //response ...
      success: function(response) {
        RenderizarInfo(response.message);
      },
      failure: function(response) {
        alert("something get wrong u.u ..... " + response.message);
      }
    });
  }
);
```

este es mi modelo

```js
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PCotiza_compras.Models {
  public class Requests {

    public string wiw {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int id {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Proyecto")]
    public string nameproject {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Esquema")]
    public int schemeid {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Fecha de solicitud")]
    public string createddate {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Respuesta Fecha")]
    public string answerdate {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Estado")]
    public int status {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Días de expiración")]
    public string expiration {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string email {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Departamento")]
    public int departmentid {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Categoría")]
    public int categoriesid {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Visto u.u_r")]
    public int seen {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Visto Fecha")]
    public string seendate {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Ediciones")]
    public int edit {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Rechazado")]
    public int rejected {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Formato")]
    public byte[] formart {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo de archivo")]
    public string ftype {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre de archivo")]
    public string fname {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Tamaño")]
    public int fsize {
      get;
      set;
    }

  }
}
```

este es mi método

```js
[WebMethod]
public JsonResult UniqueRequest(int idx) {

  string cs = "Data Source=DMX87025;Initial Catalog=DB_PCC;Integrated Security=True";
  string sql = "SELECT [nameproject],[wiw],[email],[schemeid],[status] FROM [DB_PCC].[dbo].[Requests]" +
    "WHERE [id] = '" + idx + "' ";

  using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs)) {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

    con.Open();
    List < Requests > req = new List < Requests > ();
    using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      while (rdr.Read()) {
        req.Add(new Requests() {
          wiw = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("wiw")),
            nameproject = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("nameproject")),
            email = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("email")),
            status = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("status")),
            schemeid = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("schemeid")),
            departmentid = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("departmentid")),
            categoriesid = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("categoriesid")),
            seen = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("seen")),
            edit = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("edit")),
            rejected = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("rejected"))

        });
      }
      con.Close();
      return Json(new {
        success = true, message = req
      }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

  }




}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos el Request de esa petición?

Comment: cuando se ejecuta el javascript , el alert muestra el valor que deseas enviar?

Comment: @CrismanCarmona listo

Comment: @Travv si, el dato lo obtengo de otra función y si lo imprime, para cerciorarme de que no envio un string, lo convierto en int desde js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi error era en mi AJAX tengo:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("UniqueRequest", "Request")',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',                  
    data: { 'id': id_x },
```

Y mi método espera un `idx`:

```
[WebMethod]
public JsonResult UniqueRequest(int idx)
{ 
     .....
}
```

Así que cambio en mi AJAX `id : x` por `idx : x` y listo.

Answer (score 2):

En la data del ajax, retira los paréntesis. Y Cambia el @Url.Action por la ruta estática.

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/Request/UniqueRequest',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {'id': id_x },
      //response ...
      success: function(response) {
        RenderizarInfo(response.message);
      },
      failure: function(response) {
        alert("something get wrong u.u ..... " + response.message);
      }
    });
```

Y cambia tu tipo de metodo en el controlador por ActionResult

```
public ActionResult UniqueRequest(int idx) { ...}
```

Comment: gracias , pero no hizo diferencia ...

Comment: No pues tampoco, estoy muy seguro que el problema está en js, porque ese metodo no me devolverá el json que necesito para renderizar mi info, y el error sigue siendo el mismo ... me dice que no le estoy mandando el parametro requerido ...

Comment: Trata cambiando el url.action

Comment: @Url.Action("Metodo", "Clase") es la forma propía de apuntar en asp.net

Comment: @Url.Action() es razor, solo trabajan  en archivos con extención .cshtml

Comment: si ocupo .cshtml